# Do we have $a\otimes 1=0$ if and only if $a=0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $S$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$ and $M$ any abelian group. For any  $a\otimes 1\in M\otimes_{\Bbb Z}S$, do we have $a\otimes 1=0$ if and only if $a=0$?

Comment: Try computing $\mathbb{Z}/n \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902109/when-is-the-map-m-mapsto-1-otimes-m-injective

Comment: @ArnaudD. If $M$ is a $S$-module, do we have $a\otimes 1=0$ if and only if $a=0$?

Comment: @rogerl If $M$ is a $S$-module, do we have $a\otimes 1=0$ if and only if $a=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Computing $\mathbb{Z}/n\otimes \mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$a\otimes_\mathbb{Z} q = a\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \left(n\cdot \frac{q}{n}\right)
= (a\cdot n)\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \frac{q}{n} = 0,$$
so that the tensor product is the zero module.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty}S_d$ be a graded ring and $M=\bigoplus\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty M_k$ a graded $S$-module, then $\forall k\in\Bbb Z$, $M_k$ is a $S_0$-module, for any $a\otimes 1\in M_k\otimes_{\Bbb Z}S_0$, we have $a\otimes 1=0$ if and only if $a=0$.

$\textbf{Proof}$:

$M_k\xrightarrow{f_k} M_k\otimes_{\Bbb Z}S_0\xrightarrow{g_k} M_k$

$f_k(a)=a\otimes 1, g_k(a\otimes s)=sa$,

then $(g_kf_k)(a)=a$,

hence $f_k$ is injective.

Comment: Are you kind to explain the notation? $M_k$, $S_0$???

Comment: @user26857 graded ring and graded module

Comment: And what has this to do with your question? I can understand that you could be interested in the case when M is an S-module, but from where came up with the grading?

Comment: @user26857 $S=\bigoplus_{d=0}^{\infty}S_d,M=\bigoplus_{-\infty}^\infty M_i$.

Comment: I know what's a graded ring and a graded module. Btw, in this case every $M_k$ is an $ S_0$-module. Why say 'If"? And I still don't understand what you proved.

Comment: @user26857  In order to prove $M(n)\cong M\otimes_SS(n)$ for any $n\in \Bbb Z$.